# How detect and handle if object is used as l-value or as r-value?

Tags: c++

I have a container class called `Properties`. I want to add to it `operator[](const std::string & name)` which will return property with specified name.

Now lets consider that there is no property with specified name. In this case I wan't to add new `Property` with specified name to my `Properties` if it is used as l-value and throw exception otherwise.

```
Properties pts;
pts.add("name1", val1);
pts.add("name2", val2);
pts["name1"] = val3; //OK
pts["name3"] = val1; //OK creating new Property with value = val1
cout << pts["name4"]; //Ooops can't find Property with name = "name4", so throwing an exception
```

Is this possible in C++? How can I write such `operator[]`?

Comment: good question. I know std::map will just default construct something at "name4" and you would be none the wiser that nothing was ever inserted there.

Comment: Yes. And that's why std::map have no const version of operator[]. It always adding new element with default value if there is no element with specified key.

Comment: Yes.  And that's why std::map<>::operator[] should be used a whole lot less often than it is.  People like it because it's "easy" but it also tends to mask errors and lead to having "invalid" things in the map.

Comment: @John: Perhpas this is supposed to be a variant of `std::map` for people who prefer the `[]` operator of Python's `dict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cover the cases you give, but not by actually checking whether lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs. I don't think it's possible to directly intercept that, so you need to provoke a different conversion instead:

- `operator[]` returns a proxy object, as John Zwinck says. Just creating this proxy object doesn't create the key.
- The proxy object has an `operator=(const V&)`, so that handles assignment by creating the key. Optionally you could also have `operator+=`, `operator++` and the rest - I'm not sure whether you mean that *any* lvalue use is OK, or just straight assignment.
- The proxy object has a conversion to `V&` which throws if the key doesn't already exist.

Edit: this seems to vaguely work, although there are use-cases it doesn't cover, such as passing the return value of `operator[]` to a function that takes `V&` and assigns to it in there. Also, hiding a proxy+conversion never results in a precisely equivalent interface to what you'd have with the original type, because implicit conversions can involve at most one user-defined conversion, and the proxy "uses up" that conversion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

struct FunnyMap;

struct ProxyValue {
    FunnyMap *ptr;
    std::string key;
    ProxyValue(const std::string &key, FunnyMap *ptr) : ptr(ptr), key(key) {}
    operator int&();
    int &operator=(int i);
};

struct FunnyMap {
    std::map<std::string, int> values;
    ProxyValue operator[](const std::string &key) {
        return ProxyValue(key, this);
    }
};

ProxyValue::operator int&() {
    if (ptr->values.count(key) != 0) {
        return ptr->values[key];
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("no key");
    }
}

int &ProxyValue::operator=(int i) {
    return ptr->values[key] = i;
}

void foo(int &i) {
    i = 4;
}

int main() {
    try {
        FunnyMap f;
        f["foo"] = 1;
        std::cout << f["foo"] << "\n";
        std::cout << f["bar"];
        // foo(f["bar"]); // also throws
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
Exception: no key
```

Answer (score 4):

You could have your `operator[]` return a proxy object rather than a plain reference to the contained value.  Then you could set a flag in the proxy when it is assigned to (i.e. when the proxy's operator= is called).  Then you could throw in the proxy's destructor if it was never assigned.  Of course you'll need to instantiate the proxy with a boolean telling it whether to require assignment (no value existed) or not (a value was already set).

I'll note that it is usually considered bad practice to throw in a destructor.  In particular, the proxy's destructor should not throw if it was called due to another exception (e.g. an error between key lookup and value assignment).  You'd probably want to skip throwing from the proxy's destructor if an exception is already in flight, and you can detect this condition with `std::uncaught_exception()`.

And finally I will reference this article about `uncaught_exception()`:
http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm

It makes two arguments against using this function.  The first is that it may sometimes return true when it is actually safe to throw.  I claim that we can live with this in your case because we are trying to provide a safety check and if we sometimes fail to provide the safety check then we are not much worse off than before.  And if we can agree that sometimes not having the check be done is OK in your case, then the second argument (the "moral" one) in the article can also be ignored (because your proxy will not have two different error handling mechanisms, it will have one which is usually effective but not always).

Comment: Unfortunately `uncaught_exception` detects the wrong condition. If `operator[]` is called *in another destructor*, which itself is called during stack unwinding for an exception, then `uncaught_exception` is `true`, but actually that code called in a destructor might want to know about and handle the error condition (although of course not propagate the exception from `operator[]` beyond the destructor). See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm

Comment: You are too fast.  I was in the middle of adding some commentary on that, with the exact same link!  What do you think of my counter-argument, which is basically that we can live with it in this case because some safety checking is better than none?

Comment: I agree the moral argument doesn't apply here. Not sure whether a partial safety check will do, though. We can document that it only applies in certain circumstances, and people do know they have extra pitfalls to avoid with code in destructors. So adding another one might not be a big deal, but it's not great. Imagine if `vector::at()` only sometimes bothered with the bounds-check, it would make a lot less sense as an interface than it does currently...